# Arrange array in descending order by real numbers values js

Tags: javascript

I am taking input from a textbox :

```
1 ziro = 8.60
2 passighat = 7.70
3 bomdila = 5.30
4 sankalan = 1.20
5 shipgyar = 1.20
6 yuksom = 0.40
7 beki_mathungari = 125.20
8 hazuah = 36.40
9 melabazar/matunga = 13.20
```

js code:

```
            var summary_table_content = $('#textbox').val();

                
            var array1 = summary_table_content.split('\n'); 
            var myarray = [];
            
            for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            
                    var line = array1[i];
                    var words       = line.split(' ');
                    var word2       = words[1];
                    var word4       = words[3];
                    myarray[word2]  = word4;    
            }
```

Now I want to arrange myarray in descending order by values and print it like this:

beki_mathungari 125.20, hazuah 36.40, melabazar/matunga 13.20, ziro 8.60, passighat 7.70, bomdila 5.30, sankalan 1.20, shipgyar 1.20, yuksom 0.40

I tried a solution from internet, it is working on integers but not with real numbers:

```
var tuples = [];

for (var key in myarray) tuples.push([key, myarray[key]]);

tuples.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a[1];
    b = b[1];

    return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
});

for (var i = 0; i < tuples.length; i++) {
    var key = tuples[i][0];
    var value = tuples[i][1];

document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML += key + " " + value + ", ";
}
```

Comment: And why doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: It is giving this:
yuksom 0.40, sankalan 1.20, shipgyar 1.20, beki_mathungari 125.20, melabazar/matunga 13.20, hazuah 36.40, bomdila 5.30, passighat 7.70, ziro 8.60,

Comment: Looks like it's sorting the price alphabetically, so you are probably putting strings into `myarray`, not numbers. The code you showed to initialize `myarray` is not valid, could you update it?

Comment: @thomas , Please look it again, i have updated it.

Comment: Thank you for completely changing the question after my answer, completely changing the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data coming from your text box are strings, even the numbers. And if you sort the strings `"125.20"` and `"13.20"`, they are sorted alphabetically, so `"125.20"` comes first because `2` comes before `3`.

What you need to do is convert the numbers to actual numbers before storing them in the array, using the `parseFloat` function:

```
                var word4       = parseFloat(words[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `myarray` isnt actually an array, it is an object. If you make this change, ordering by the values and joining the key/values is as easy as:

```js
var myarray = {};

myarray["ziro"] = 8.60;
myarray["passighat"] = 7.70;
myarray["bomdila"] = 5.30;
myarray["sankalan"] = 1.20;
myarray["shipgyar"] = 1.20;
myarray["yuksom"] = 0.40;
myarray["beki_mathungari"] = 125.20;
myarray["hazuah"] = 36.40;
myarray["melabazar/matunga"] = 13.20;

var result = Object.entries(myarray)
                  .sort( (a,b) => b[1] - a[1])
                  .map( ([key,value]) => `${key} ${value.toFixed(2)}`)
                  .join(", ");
                  
console.log(result)
```

---

Edit after your update. You've changed the question to be about converting string to a number. This step just needs to be done using `parseFloat`and then the above solution still works:

```js
var input = `1 ziro = 8.60
2 passighat = 7.70
3 bomdila = 5.30
4 sankalan = 1.20
5 shipgyar = 1.20
6 yuksom = 0.40
7 beki_mathungari = 125.20
8 hazuah = 36.40
9 melabazar/matunga = 13.20`;

var result = input.split("\n")
                  .map(x => {
                    [word0,word1,word2,word3] = x.split(" ");
                    return [word1,parseFloat(word3)]
                  })                  
                  .sort( (a,b) => b[1] - a[1])
                  .map( ([key,value]) => `${key} ${value.toFixed(2)}`)
                  .join(", ");
console.log(result)
```